# How to obtain google OAuth 2 or service access token c# .net 3.5 (Unity) for google sheets

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

Does anyone know a way to get a google oAuth2 access token and then use this in a WWW (or just a web request) to retrieve data from a private spreadsheet.

I have managed to do (what i believe is getting) an access code using the way described in the google sheets v3 examples and this opens google page opening to accept authorisation and copy the access code out. However when i use this code in the web call google provides it fails (it asks me for an api key which the oAuth should replace but still fails with a valid api key)

i was looking at the references on the documentation namely https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#callinganapi for putting my access_token in so it would look like the code segement below and from my understanding should then work. I'm guessing my access code is wrong but not 100% sure if this is the case

```
        WWW a = new WWW("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1MNqof6SVUFUhyPxca-bSSfhlcHNOG80o29GPHaJYZXU/values/A1:D4?" + "access_token=" + accessToken);

    yield return a;

    Debug.Log(a.text);
```

I have looked through the examples on how to read and write as well from here developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#callinganapi using requests but I need to authorise these and grant permission.

Looking through the other examples they show using a download that is .net 4 and with unity only supporting .net 3.5 i need to go about this a different way such as a WWW request to get a access token if expired and then use that access token in the actually request for the data.

Answer (score 0):

You may check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth). OAuth 2.0 is the authorization protocol used by Google APIs. You should get familiar with the protocol by reading these links: [The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) and
[Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). To begin, obtain OAuth 2.0 client credentials from the [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/). Then your client application requests an access token from the Google Authorization Server, extracts a token from the response, and sends the token to the Google API that you want to access. For an interactive demonstration of using OAuth 2.0 with Google (including the option to use your own client credentials), experiment with the [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).

Comment: So i have been reading through the documentation and i still a bit lost on what I need to send to get the token. I understand getting the API set up and you client secret etc and then how to process the return request. I know i need to send client is and secret just not sure where i would send that to and what else i need in the unity WWW class. I have run through the playground to get the access token and if i copy that into my unity application everything works, however i need to know how to generate that within unity for when that token expires and this is where im getting lost